# What are the white bugs on my Aeonium and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, succulents, insects, mealybugs

Some of my [Aeonium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeonium) plants have had this bug issue for month now, so here's how the plant and the bug looks like:

[image]

I have a 35mm macro lens, and I shot 1 bug (and killed it)

[image]

This bug is white and produced some sort of white powder on my plant's leaves.
Usually they hide in the back of the leaves, so until today I thought it was a fungal issue.

My guess is that this is a [scale insect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect), but I'm not that sure.

What are these bugs, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mealybug infestation - looks like mostly larval. I've found that a mixture of 1 teaspoon of dish detergent per cup of water has been an effective control. used as a spray over the entire plant. Once the population has been controlled, wash the leaves carefully to remove residue.

Comment: It's mealybug alright.  Successful control requires at least three applications of soap and water at five to seven day intervals.  This is to catch the eggs that hatch after the first spray.

Comment: Thanks @kevinsky and Musser. Do I have to soak the soil too? Since I've found some of them in the pot mix.

Comment: If you have mealy bug in the soil: root mealybugs then a soil drench is necessary too. They are harder to get rid of.